# android how change marker id

Tags: java, android

I get a data of the marker from mysql database like title and id :

```
    @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
                for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
                   HashMap<String, String> marker = result.get(i);
                   LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng")));
                   String T = marker.get("name");
                   String pid = marker.get("pid");
                   addMarker(latlng, T, pid);             
                }
```

then i add the marker to the map :

```
private void addMarker(LatLng latlng,String T, String pid) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    markerOptions.title(T);
    map.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

but now i have to send the id with the Title to the next activity :

```
 @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker m) {
    Intent nextScreen = new Intent (Map.this, Detail.class);
    String title = m.getTitle();
    nextScreen.putExtra("name", title);
    startActivityForResult(nextScreen, 101);
    }
```

So what is the solution to send the id ?

Comment: What problem are you having?  You can simply add it as another extra?

Comment: My problem is to send the id in the second activity unless it appears in the infoWindow ?

Answer (score 0):

You can using this Library :

https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/

It has method called `setData()` and `getData()` and you need also create your custom class that contain the data you need to post in it like

```
public class MarkerData{

    int ID ;
    String title ;
    double lng , lat 

 }
```

and in create `HashMap` that will hold object from your class for each marker :

```
HashMap<String, MarkerData> marker
```

Answer (score 0):

easy and poor way...

you declare in your snippet divide by a "#"

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(LATITUDE,
                                    LONGITUDE)
                            )
                    ).title(gap.getName())
                            .icon(icon)
                            .snippet(YOUR_ID+"#"+snippetstring)
                    );
```

For you get the value back you use the SPLIT

```
 @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View popup=inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

            TextView tv=(TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.title);

            String[] separated = marker.getSnippet().split("#");
            String id = separated[0];
            String snippet = separated[1];

            tv.setText(marker.getTitle());
            tv = (TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet);

            tv.setText(snippet);

            return(popup);
        }
```